# Conditional recoding in R

Tags: r, recode

Here is an excerpt from an `R` `data.frame` which consist of indicators. It can be seen that for some rows the indictors switch to 1 until the end of the row while others switch back to zero.

```
       [,18] [,19] [,20] [,21] [,22] [,23] [,24] 
   [1,]     0     0     0     0     0     0     0 
   [2,]     0     0     0     0     1     1     1  
   [6,]     0     0     0     0     0     0     0  
   [7,]     0     0     1     0     0     1     1  
   [8,]     0     0     0     0     0     0     0  
   [9,]     0     1     0     1     1     1     1  
  [10,]     1     1     1     1     1     1     1  
  [11,]     1     0     1     1     0     1     1
```

I want to identify the point in each row when a sequence of `1` does not change back to zero anymore to the end of the row. This should be indicated by all elements set to `1` after this point, while the previous elements are `0`.  The result would be:

```
       [,18] [,19] [,20] [,21] [,22] [,23] [,24] 
   [1,]     0     0     0     0     0     0     0 
   [2,]     0     0     0     0     1     1     1  
   [6,]     0     0     0     0     0     0     0  
   [7,]     0     0     0     0     0     1     1  
   [8,]     0     0     0     0     0     0     0  
   [9,]     0     0     0     1     1     1     1  
  [10,]     1     1     1     1     1     1     1  
  [11,]     0     0     0     0     0     1     1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take the cumulative min from the end of each row:

```
t(apply(m, 1, function(r) rev(cummin(rev(r)))))

#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
#[1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
#[2,]    0    0    0    0    1    1    1
#[3,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
#[4,]    0    0    0    0    0    1    1
#[5,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
#[6,]    0    0    0    1    1    1    1
#[7,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
#[8,]    0    0    0    0    0    1    1
```

---

*Data*: m is an integer matrix consisting of 1 and 0

```
dput(m)
structure(c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Dim = c(8L, 7L))
```